# What is the appropriate tense for factual statements after a stative verb in the past tense?

Tags: tense, stative-verbs

Assuming that cats are evil (they aren't), which is the correct way of saying this?

"I believed that cats are evil."

"I believed that cats were evil."

My confusion arises because I want to express that the act of believing occurred in the past, but also that the belief was and is true.

Comment: If you want to explicitly express both past and present (it's not entirely clear from the question), then you have use a conjunction: *I believed that cats were evil then, and I still believe that they're evil now.*

Answer (score 2):

Both are possible. Normally the tense would match:

> I believed cats were evil.

However, if you want to emphasise that you believed something that was unchangeable you could use the simple present:

> I believed that Elvis is dead.